# Heroku Memory Error with PHP and reading large file from S3

Tags: php, memory, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the AWS 2.3.2 SDK for PHP to try to pull down a large file (~4g) from S3 using their stream wrapper, which should allow me to use fopen / fwrite to write the file to disk and not buffer into memory.

Here is the reference:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html#downloading-data

Here is my code:

```
public function download()
    {

        $client = S3Client::factory(array(
                    'key'    => getenv('S3_KEY'),
                    'secret' => getenv('S3_SECRET')
                    ));

        $bucket = getenv('S3_BUCKET');
        $client->registerStreamWrapper();

        try {
            error_log("calling download");
            // Open a stream in read-only mode
            if ($stream = fopen('s3://'.$bucket.'/tmp/'.$this->getOwner()->filename, 'r')) {
                // While the stream is still open
                if (($fp = @fopen($this->getOwner()->path . '/' . $this->getOwner()->filename, 'w')) !== false){

                    while (!feof($stream)) {
                        // Read 1024 bytes from the stream
                        fwrite($fp, fread($stream, 1024));
                    }
                    fclose($fp);
                }
            // Be sure to close the stream resource when you're done with it
            fclose($stream);
        }
```

The file downloads but I continually get error messages from Heroku:

> 2013-08-22T19:57:59.537740+00:00 heroku[run.9336]: Process running
>   mem=515M(100.6%) 2013-08-22T19:57:59.537972+00:00 heroku[run.9336]:
>   Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Which leads me to believe this is still buffering to memory somehow. I've tried to use https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler, but got a Seg Fault.

I also tried to download the file using cURL with CURLOPT_FILE  option to write directly to the disk and i'm still running out of memory. The odd thing is according to `top` my php instance is using 223m of memory so not even half of the allowed 512.

Anybody have any ideas? I'm running this from php 5.4.17 cli to test.

Comment: Also tried php copy command, and using fflush($fp) to flush the write buffer. This should NOT be exhausting the memory

Comment: Can you change to `rb` and `wb` to read and write files in binary mode? Also, this shouldn't change anything but just to make sure - do you get the same results if you use a temporary variable to hold the data between reading and writing?

Comment: tried that doesn't change anything... also to be clear: from the the command line - $ curl -O http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip   also causes a memory error, which I think is the issue. It may be a spurious error I don't know, I have a support request in with Heroku

Comment: Is it possible that heroku dynos have a maximum hard drive size and are throwing R14s for that instead of some more specific error? Can you query the available hard drive space and watch it during your app execution or `curl` download and see if the error happens at a consistent file size?

Comment: 559G available on /tmp .. memory error happens when file hits about one gig, so not sure if its buffering somehow or what. Heroku cli's don't have a lot of tools to diagnose

Comment: Why do you silence the errors when calling `fopen` ? What happens if you don't ?

Comment: what happens when you output memory_get_peak_usage() from inside the while loop?

Answer (score 2):

Did you already try with a 2x dyno, those have 1GB of memory?

What you also can try is downloading the file by executing a curl command in PHP. It's not the cleanest way but it will be much faster/more reliable and memory friendly.

```
exec("curl -O http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/file.zip", $output);
```

This example is for a public URL. If you don't want to make your S3 files public you can always create a signed URL and use that in combination with the curl command.

Comment: Yes, and then I get

 2013-08-23T14:30:06.785538+00:00 heroku[run.7646]: Process running mem=1024M(100.0%)
2013-08-23T14:30:06.785658+00:00 heroku[run.7646]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Comment: Maybe you should try the curl implementation like I explained in my edited post above.

Comment: Tried that implementation and same result: 

2013-08-23T19:23:29.446439+00:00 heroku[run.2306]: Process running mem=1024M(100.0%)
2013-08-23T19:23:29.447246+00:00 heroku[run.2306]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)